# ISPConfig3 Domain points to a subdirectory of Web

Tags: ispconfig-3

Have a DocRoot /var/www/clients/client2/web4/web and the domain mytest.tld should point to a directory /var/www/clients/client2/web4/web/public.
The DocRoot should not be changed.
How can I make the domain point to the /public subdirectory?

THANKS

I tried to work with the Apache directives. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: The ispconfig-3 have no followers. You're gonna have to add something more wide spread to get visibility.